# use the same AJAX function two times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Im beginner in AJAX & JS so please bear with me.

I have an AJAX that will work in 2 events :

1. When the page loaded
2. When a button clicked

This AJAX have an `url` with some variables for pagination :

```
url: "http://localhost/myurl/" + keyword + "/" + limit + "/" + offset
```

This AJAX is working fine when the page loaded, but **i dont know how to call/use it again when the user click the button.**

And i put the `.click` function in the AJAX it self, so basically i need to recall the parent. This is a code to show you what i want to do :

```
$.ajax({
        url: "example" + limit + offset
        type: "GET",
        error : function(jq, st, err) {
            alert(st + " : " + err);
        },
        success: function(result){
        $("#btnLoad").click(function(){
                    //recall this AJAX again here
                                            offset = (page - 1) * limit;
                    page++;
                });
        }
        });
```

I know copy-paste the code might work, but i dont want to do that because the AJAX is pretty long.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks :D

Comment: you can extract the function inside `click()` to be a new Javascript function. Re-use the new function on `click()` and `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Simply just define a function with required arguments and call that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add it in the event handler, and trigger the event on pageload:

```
$("#btnLoad").on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "example" + limit + offset
        type: "GET",
        ....
    });
}).trigger('click');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry i dont really understand your code. If i use your code, does it mean that the $.ajax just will work when i click a button? I need it on the page load too.

Comment: It will work in both cases, because the script adds the handler to the click event(so it's appended, which means that when you click the element the event is fired and the ajax call is executed), but it is also fired just after it is appended, and the triggering will happen on page load.

Comment: @BlazeTama Its trigerring click event. So Ajax gets called on page load as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its working now :D However, theres a problem with the pagination, please kindly see it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015131/pagination-with-ajax-url

Answer (score 3):

You can abstract the AJAX call out. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //this is called when the page is loaded

  //variable that hold your offset and limit in the scope of the this function
  var limit = 10,
      offset = 0,
      page = 1;

  function ajaxCall(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "example" + limit + offset
        type: "GET",
        error : function(jq, st, err) {
            alert(st + " : " + err);
        },
        success: function(result){
          offset = (page - 1) * limit;
          page++;
        });
  };

  //register event for click on button
  $("#btnLoad").on('click', ajaxCall);


  //do the initial ajax call
  ajaxCall();

});
```

This is not a perfect solution but should get you closer to where you want to be. 
Things to consider here are:

- what happens when a user clicks the button a second time before the success callback has updated the offset and page?

Answer (score 2):

*Note:this will be inside the $(document).ready()*

your ajax on click:

```
$("#my_btn").on("click",my_click_ajax)

        function my_click_ajax(){
                $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'your_url',
                 data: {a:some_value},
                 success: function(data) {
                        alert(data)
                 }
             });
            }
```

your onload ajax:

*Note:this will be outside the $(document).ready()*

```
window.onload=my_onload_ajax();
    function my_onload_ajax(){
         $.ajax({
                     type: 'POST',
                     url: 'your_url',
                     data: {a:some_value},
                     success: function(data) {
                            alert(data)
                     }
                 });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. How about on the pageload?

Answer (score 2):

You can extract your ajax call in method:

```
// here you should to define 'limit' and 'offset' variables with init values
$("#btnLoad").on('click', method); 

var method = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "example" + limit + offset
        type: "GET",
        ....
    });
}

method(); // call method on page load
```

Answer (score 1):

put your .ajax file into $(document).ready()
like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#yourid').click(function(){
   //some code here...
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Shivan said: create a function and call it when the page loads and when something is clicked. Like this:

```
$(function(){
    MyAJAXFunction();
    $(".button").click(function(){
        MyAJAXFunction();
    });
});

function MyAJAXFunction() {
    // AJAX call here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to the ajax to fire when the user clicks a button.
It would be better if you create a function outside of the ajax call.
Then call that function when it is successful.

```
div id="callAjaxRequestButton">Ajax Request</div>

$( "#callAjaxRequestButton" ).click(function() {  
                $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: "http://localhost/myurl/" + keyword + "/" + limit + "/" + offset,
                 data: {a:some_value},
              success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data)
              }
             });
);
});
```