# pagination with AJAX url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Im beginner in AJAX & JS so please bear with me.

I use this AJAX for the pagination :

```
 $(function () {
     var keyword = window.localStorage.getItem("keyword");

     //pagination
     var limit = 3;
     var page = 0;
     var offset = 0;

     $("#btnLoad").on('click', function () {
         page++;
         if (page != 0)
             offset = (page - 1) * limit;

         $.ajax({
             url: "http://localhost/jwmws/index.php/jwm/search/msmall/" + keyword + "/" + limit + "/" + offset, //This is the current doc
             type: "GET",
             error: function (jq, st, err) {
                 alert(st + " : " + err);
             },
             success: function (result) {
                 alert("offset=" + offset + " page =" + page);
                 //generate search result
                 $('#search').append('<p style="float:left;">Search for : ' + keyword + '</p>' + '<br/>' + '<p>Found ' + result.length + ' results</p>');

                 if (result.length == 0) {
                     //temp
                     alert("not found");
                 } else {
                     for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                         //generate <li>
                         $('#list').append('<li class="box"><img class="picture" src="images/HotPromo/tagPhoto1.png"/><p class="name"><b>Name</b></p><p class="address">Address</p><p class="hidden"></p></li>');
                     }

                     var i = 0;
                     $(".box").each(function () {
                         var name, address, picture, id = "";
                         if (i < result.length) {
                             name = result[i].name;
                             address = result[i].address;
                             picture = result[i].boxpicture;
                             id = result[i].mallid;
                         }

                         $(this).find(".name").html(name);
                         $(this).find(".address").html(address);
                         $(this).find(".picture").attr("src", picture);
                         $(this).find(".hidden").html(id);
                         i++;
                     });

                     $(".box").click(function () {
                         //alert($('.hidden', this).html());
                         window.localStorage.setItem("id", $('.hidden', this).html());
                         $("#pagePort").load("pages/MallDetail.html", function () {});
                     });

                 }
             }
         });
     }).trigger('click');

 });
```

Please notice that i use the variables for pagination in the `url:`. I tried to alert the page and offset variable, and its working fine.

However, the AJAX only working for the first page (when page load). The rest is not working even though the page and offset variable's value is true.

Theres no warning/error in console. The data just not shown.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks :D

Comment: Does your button `#btnLoad` exist?

Comment: Whay jQuery version do you use?

Comment: @putvande yes its exist, i have checked it :D

Comment: @putvande its the newest one

Answer (score -1):

It is a bit hard to debug your code when the whole HTML is missing.
Could you put your code into [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), both HTML and JS.

Comment: This isn't an answer. Consider to put this in as a comment.

Comment: Sorry. I did't have enough reputation to add it in a comment.